# Electron-builder - Set environment variables during app installation

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have built application .exe installer using electron-builder and JavaScript.

I am trying to set up environment variable during or right after the installation of the application. It will hold value of the installation directory of the application chosen by the user during the install wizard.

I am very much stuck, can you share some ideas on this please?

Thanks